# Cramer's Rule - Geometrical Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Based on the image above we have:

```
u1 = area(b, a2) / area(a1, a2)
u2 = area(b, a1) / area(a1, a2)
```

The books says: 
"An easy way to see how these ratios of areas correspond to u1 and u2 is to shear the parallelograms formed by b, a2 and b, a1 onto the a1 and a2 axes, respectively.".

I've ended up with:

[image]

*My question*

Did I draw it properly, does the ratios based on my drawings make sense?

Comment: Write down the initial linear system before writing the result of Cramer's (not Carmer) formulas